# CSS: Height not correct when resized

Tags: html, css

I've been stuck with this problem for a long time now. Whenever i resize my window the CSS acts really weird. I'll show you pictures because it's hard for me to explain.

How it should be:

[image: How it should be]

How it shouldn't be:

[image: How it shouldn't be]

Even though I use procentage height instead of pixels it gets all wrong.

I've linked the source code here, same problem occours on resize window:

jsfiddle.net/nxa747ca/

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Also note that the copyright policy at JSFiddle technically doesn't allow someone else to edit that code into the post, so you'll need to [edit] this question yourself. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296568/op-posted-code-in-comment-user-brought-it-to-question-via-edit/296627#296627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you have `position:fixed` and `position: absolute` on your classes.

First thing first fix the order of your html:

`<div class="chat-messages"></div>
 <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Type your message">`

On your css remove `position: absolute;` on `chat-messages` and `position: fixed;` on `.chat-name` they should be just the default `position: relative;`